# How to remove xml namespace declaration using dom4j?

Tags: xpath, dom4j

I am using [dom4j](/questions/tagged/dom4j) and [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) to parse a xml file,and I met a question: if there is an *xmlns* declaration,then xPath will return nothing,however,if the namespace declaration is removed,then xPath works fine,and will reutrn the expected value.

Here is my java test file:

```
public class XPathTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        testXPath();
    }


    public static void testXPath(){
        Document doc=getDocument("file/info.xml");
        Element root=doc.getRootElement();
        /*boolean removeFlag=root.remove(root.getNamespace());
        System.out.println("removeFlag:\t"+removeFlag);*/
        Node node=root.selectSingleNode("list[@id='002']/name");
        System.out.println(node.getText());
    }


    public static Document getDocument(String file){
        Document document=null;
        SAXReader saxReader=null;
        try {
            saxReader=new SAXReader();
            document= saxReader.read(new File(file));
        } catch (DocumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return document;
    }
}
```

Here is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<info xmlns="http://fit42.sys42.vwg/emx">  
   <intro>信息</intro>  
    <list id='001'>  
        <head>auto_userone</head>  
        <name>Jordy</name>  
        <number>12345678</number>  
        <age>20</age>  
        <sex>Man</sex>  
        <hobby>看电影</hobby>  
    </list>  

   <list id='002'>  
        <head>auto_usertwo</head>  
        <name>tester</name>  
         <number>34443678</number>  
         <age>18</age>  
         <sex>Man</sex>  
         <hobby>玩游戏</hobby>  
     </list>

     <taichung id='003'>
       <mayor>Jason Hu</mayor>
     </taichung>  

</info>
```

When I run my test program,I got a NullPointerException stack.However,if I remove the namespace declaration for the xml and make it as below,then everything works fine:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<info>  
   <intro>信息</intro>  
    <list id='001'>  
        <head>auto_userone</head>  
        <name>Jordy</name>  
        <number>12345678</number>  
        <age>20</age>  
        <sex>Man</sex>  
        <hobby>看电影</hobby>  
    </list>  

   <list id='002'>  
        <head>auto_usertwo</head>  
        <name>tester</name>  
         <number>34443678</number>  
         <age>18</age>  
         <sex>Man</sex>  
         <hobby>玩游戏</hobby>  
     </list>

     <taichung id='003'>
       <mayor>Jason Hu</mayor>
     </taichung>  

</info>
```

But due to the xml file is get from other companies and I can not modify the structure of it,so I tried to remove the namespace declaration in my progaram,I modified the *testXPath* method as below,the remove action return true and I still can see the xml declaration in the rootElement,so the program still generate a NullPointerException,I do not know why:

```
public static void testXPath(){
    Document doc=getDocument("file/info.xml");
    Element root=doc.getRootElement();
    boolean removeFlag=root.remove(root.getNamespace());
    System.out.println("removeFlag:\t"+removeFlag);
    Node node=root.selectSingleNode("list[@id='002']/name");
    System.out.println(node.getText());
}
```

***So my question is:could anyone give me some advice on how to solve it?***

Comment: There's usually an overload of SelectSingleNode, that takes a NamespaceManager instance. You don't remove the namespace, you pass it, so then XPath will look for the fully qualified match. Which is in fact the point of namespaces.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson I tried as you wrote but I did not find the overload method in dom4j API,could you make your answer more clearly?Thanks

Comment: Why don't you simply actually _use_ the namespace? Or at least use the wildcard namespace operator (i.e. ` *:list[@id='002']/*:name`). After all, that's the intended use of namespaces.

Comment: @dirkk,I have tried as you wrote but failed with Invalid xPath express  in the eclipse console.

Comment: @flyFox argh, it's because the asterisk is interpreted by SO as markup. So before the colon there should be an asterisk, which is the namespace wildcard operator. Also, you might want to read some basic stuff about XML namespaces as it is an important concept.

Comment: @dirkk,thank you for your answer,I will read it later,could you tell me how to query it by using the actually namespance?I do not want to use the wildcard namespace.Thanks

Comment: @dirkk, thank you very much,I just tried and got right answer!It's due to my poor knowledge about XML namespace.

Answer (score 0):

hy,

your problem is in xPath, if the element name or attribute has name with caratere utf8 or in your xml you have speciefied a NameSpace you must use function in xPath.

this is code work:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    testXPath();
}

public static void testXPath() {

    Document doc = getDocument("C:\\test\\test.xml");

    if (doc != null) {
        Element root = doc.getRootElement();

        Element element = (Element) root.selectSingleNode("./*[name()='list'][@id='002']/*[name()='name']");

        if (element != null) {
            System.out.println(element.asXML());
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("element not found");
        }
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("File XML not found/ Error parse XML file");
    }

}

public static Document getDocument(String pathname) {

    Document document = null;

    SAXReader saxReader = null;

    try {

        saxReader = new SAXReader();

        document = saxReader.read(new File(pathname));
    }
    catch (DocumentException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return document;
}
```